# Need help finding SSH Token for Immersive Labs Going Places

Tags: ssh, token, scp

I am trying to complete the Immersive Labs Going Places Lab. Using SCP I need to copy a file from a server to the host. I have no problem copying the file and opening it on the host machine. The question is "Copy the file ‘ssh_key’ from ‘alice’ back to localhost. What is the token you receive?" I have no idea what they are talking about when they say token. I have tried copying the contents of the file I copied but it isn't the write answer.
I bet it is something incredibly simple that I am just missing.

I am using the command  scp alice@serverip:ssh_key targetfile.txt

As I said, I can copy the file no problem, but IDK what a token is!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/84062), "token" can be used to reference the public key.

Since you have copied a private key, you can [extract its public key](https://askubuntu.com/a/53555/5470) with:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f targetfile.txt > ssh_key.pub
```

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me:

scp alice@serverip:ssh_key ssh_key